# intervention image for thumbnails Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, thumbnails

Hi I'm trying to get thumbnails with the same TimThumbs, I'm using Intervention Image and Intervention Cache.

My thumbnails now have the url structure:

> thumbs/122x88?src=upload/news/news_40942c468090384b8135a6bbb79f631d.png

How do I get an address like:

> /thumbs/upload/news/122x88-news_40942c468090384b8135a6bbb79f631d.png

I would like to remove this `"?src="?`

My route code is as follows:

```
Route::get('thumbs/{imgw}x{imgh}/', function ($imgw,$imgh)
{
    $src = \Input::get('src', 1);
    $width = $imgw;
    $height = $imgh;

    $cacheimage = \Image::cache(function($image) use ($src,$width,$height) {
        return $image->make($src)->resize($width,$height);
    }, 1, false);
    return Response::make($cacheimage, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
});
```

I tried to remove `"\Input::get"`, but It's not working.

Comment: Just as a heads up - When you have routes for images, you're essentially forcing the entire Laravel application to bootstrap for the request for each image on your page. **That can become super cumbersome!**

Comment: I have about 6,000 images ... so I have to create 6 thousand thumbnails?
On my site (which I'm bringing to Laravel) I'm using timthumb, and I have no problem with resources...

Comment: Yeah, but you can't compare an apple to an orange. Wordpress is very simple; there isn't a large bootstraping going on under the hood for each of these images, so of course it won't take as long. With Laravel, you're setting up the IoC, binding providers, creating the request, filtering with Middleware, etc. It's proper software.

Comment: But here's the thing, these thumbnails should be super minuscule in size. The performance increase from serving a flat image as opposed to the amount of storage needed is a no brainer. 6000 thumbnails might account for, say, 150mb? That's really nothing

Comment: Thanks @ohgodwhy, but I just on the homepage, I need pictures in different sizes 426x209, With time, when there is new news that takes their place, the images will become 122x88, Then on the "archive" page, the images will be 255x135... It means creating three thumbnails for each image ... So what's the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out how I get the pictures on my website:
https://www.verhuisdieren.nl/

So on imagecache.php ( config file ), i just setup the route for all the images ( lets say 'route' => 'images' ), and when I upload images, I upload them on the storage folder and rename them before I save them. From Laravel 5.3 you can save it with the FileUploader class like this:

```
$request->get('image')->save('new-name');
```

and this then loads it without any prefix.

So recap: don't make a route for it, you already have that on your imagecache.php file. You can then get the route something like this:

```
url(config('imagecache.route'), ['YOUR-SIZE', 'FILENAME']);
```

EDITED:

config file example ( the config file imagecache.php ):

https://pastebin.com/sf5CusYJ

Comment: Sorry ignorance but the documentation is very vague, Imagecache.route what does it refer to? Could you make me a configuration example? Using caches for the resize, did you encounter slowdown issues? I've seen your site, and it's just the result I'm trying to get

Comment: They have a route set for this one the background, so that whatever route you give to that 'route' parameter, it will be known as the route for taking your image. So then all you have to do is to call that "url" function which gives you the image url with that crop-size.